# how to combine multtiple values in preg_match_all

Tags: php

I  have a `preg_match_all` function in PHP. Here is the code.

```
preg_match_all('#"sourceName":"(\S+)","verified":false,"targetId":(\S+),"sourceId"#',$html,$matches);
$nu=$matches[1];
$nuu=$matches[3];
$n=implode($nu,"<br>");
```

I am getting two values `$nu`(is equal to any name) and `$nuu`(is equal to a userid). I need to save both in this format, suppose `$nu=vina and $nuu=73838833`
so the format will be `@vina(73838833)`. Now how to do it please help me.

Comment: Add this to your question: 1) value of $html 2) print_r($matches); after the preg_match_all 3) $nu is a string, "<br>" is a string as well, the use of implode here is not good.  What are you trying to do?  4) if you want `@vina(73838833)`, do `$wantedstring = '@' . $nu . '(' . $nuu . ')';`

Comment: Are you just asking about the most trivial variable/string concatenation here, or what …? _“Now how to do it please help me”_ - this is so basic, it should not even be on here IMHO. You should go work through some beginner tutorials instead … giving those is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: thanks you for the answer but problem is that i have many values and i want all the values in this format supose that i have a txt file which contents many and i want to write all like this then how it will work its only show 1 values

Answer (score 0):

It is very basic of PHP string concatenation. Here, the concatenation operator ('.') should be used which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. Try like this:

```
$output = '@' . $nu . '(' . $nuu . ')';
echo $output;
```

Comment: thanks you for the answer but problem is that i have many values and i want all the values in this format supose that i have a txt file which contents many and i want to write all like this then how it will work its only show 1 values